Text alignment with flushright centers my text instead, is this a bug?
Using TeXstudio. I've been trying to align a piece of poetry I wrote to the right side of the page.
Essentially, I want to achieve a two column structure with their alignment being left/right flushed. Left alignment works on the right column side but the left one doesn't properly align itself to the right, despite all my attempts so far. This behavior also happens without me using multicolumns, so that is not the problem here.
See image for a rough example:

All info I found so far was to use \begin{flushright} some text here \end{flushright}.
I also tried \hfill{} but that didn't do anything at all.
I understand it so that this should put my text exactly on the right side edge of the page/column/etc.
What happens instead is this: My text gets centered. Here an image. 
Is this a mistake I made? I started using this software a day ago. When I remove this flush command it uses the default alignment, I don't want that either. I tried to see if center for some reason does anything but that also, no change, just the normal center alignment.
Is my editor perhaps bugged? Should I contact the TeXstudio dev?
My full code stems from the book preset, which I used to write small chapters and use alignments in there as I see fit. I didn't do anything out of the ordinary there, so I don't think that's the reason.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\begin{document}

\author{TeXstudio Team}
\title{blank}
\date{January 2013}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\include{./TeX_files/Foreword}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/mainchapter01}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter01}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter02}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter03}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter04}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter05}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter06}
\include{./TeX_files/mainchapter02}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter07}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter08}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter09}


\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}


My chapter consists mostly of these code lines
\chapter*{name}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{displayname}

Published: -
%\fontsize{12}{15.2}\selectfont
\vspace{0.5cm}
\newline
text
\vspace{7cm}
\newline
 \newline
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{flushright}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-15}{-15}
\noindent text\newline 
text
\newline
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft} Dreht sich nur in eine Richtung.\newline
Dreh dich nicht um.
\vspace{0.15cm}
\newline
text
\vspace{0.5cm}
\newline
\end{flushleft} 
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{multicols}
text
\vspace{0.5cm}
\newline
text\newline
text
\vspace{0.5cm}
\newline


It might also be that there is possibly a smarter way to format poetry, I haven't found one yet.
I hope somebody can help me out or advise me what to do next. Thanks in advance.

please post a small complete document that shows the problem. We can not run it with all the \include and there is no need to post a multi-file source, just make a small example where the alignment fails.

but use \\  rather than \newline to force a line break in flushleft, flushright, or center

latex standard classes have a verse  environment for poetry and there are many packages such as poetry.sty specifically for poetry layout

Alright, on it. Thanks. Will update once I got an example down that breaks in my environment.

Thanks to David Carlisle for the suggestion. I made an example and figured out what was causing this.
Using \newline doesn't work with this alignment style, that's correct. \\ as a line break works. Here a simple test with code on the side to compare both variants. Using \begin{flushright} text here \end{flushright} works for me now.
Will replace all \newline with \\ now :)

Edit: Thanks for the suggestion, I added a code example using the book preset. You can copy this to test in your own environment.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{flushright}  
    example text with\\ 
    double line breaks\\
    example text with\\ 
    double line breaks
\end{flushright}    
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{flushright}  
    example text with\newline 
    newline breaks \newline
    example text with\newline 
    newline breaks
\end{flushright}
    

\end{document}


Although this answer is probably correct, it would be far more useful if you included a minimal working example from \documentclass to \end{document} instead of a screenshot of a piece of code. This would allow the code to be copied and checked directly. This would not only help in evaluating your answer, but would also help other people with similar problems. Both typing in code from screenshots and speculative additions are prone to errors.

Thank you, I added that now. Hope this helps others, too.
